# LM339 Comparator IC is not responding to any input

Tags: integrated-circuit, comparator, ldr

I came into Electronics through Arduino, so pardon me if my knowledge about non-Arduino circuits is somewhat silly. I am preparing a small electronics project for my school with LDRs to detect light levels. With, an Arduino I could easily detect light levels and when they go down a threshold, I turn on a relay.

But, I wanted to make this without an Arduino, so I though of using an LM339 Comparator. I connected pin 3 of IC to Vcc and pin 12 to Ground. Pin 4 has an input lower than the input on pin 5 which receives input from Vcc. Lastly, I had the output 1 from pin 2 connected to an LED.

This circuit is only to test the comparator. If it works I am going to change the reference voltage and in place of the LED place a transistor. Here is a quick circuit Diagram I created:[image]

But, the LED does not glow. Even if I switch the inupts, the LED does not glow. I tested this in circuits.io, the online simulator. It works perfect there. But, the problem persists on the breadboard.

How do I get the LED to glow in my circuit on the bench?

UPDATE: I just got the LED glowing with the help of Raj, but how can I connect the base of a transistor in place of the LED.

Comment: 1) **ALWAYS** use a series resistor when using a LED, in case of doubt use 1 k ohm. 2) The LM339 cannot supply current, it can only sink it. So place the LED + resistor between Vcc and the output, swap the inputs (as now the LED will be on when the output is LOW) and the LED will light up.

Comment: You should also be aware of the common-mode input range of the LM339, which is zero to Vcc - 2V.  If both inputs are above this range, the output will be low regardless of which is higher

Comment: It sounds the online simulator isn't very good, to be honest.

Answer (score 8):

LM339 comparator output is open collector mean you can make the led glow by connecting the anode to vcc and cathode to the output pin.

> please note:

add a series resistor to the LED or else the LED will make a short to the open collector output transistor of the LM339

[image: simple comparator]

Comment: Hah,  beat me to it!  You need a resistor between Vcc and the output.  (5 k ohm traditional?)

Comment: Can you also tell me how I can connect the output to base of a NPN transistor ? That's what I plan on doing later.

Comment: I had updated the circuit, the comparator has a internal NPN transistor, with collector connected to output, it can sink current around 10 - 15 ma check the data sheet of your device

Comment: Thanks Raj, the circuit works perfectly ! Chose this as the correct answer. Thanks !

Comment: Hey, your updated circuit looks to be malfunctioning. The LED keeps on glowing. Can you tell me whats wrong ?

Comment: is it with switch on/off position or switch in both state?

Comment: Its in both states. Also the earlier ciruit worked. I could glow a single LED but only the transistor does not work.

Comment: updated the circuit including a potential divided input to the -v input so that the comparator will be in known state, pressing switch will toggle the output

Answer (score 3):

The LM339 has open-collector outputs, which means that they can sink current but not source it.

In order to see any changes in the output state, you'll have to connect your LED (WITH a current-limiting resistor!) between the positive supply and the output.

Comment: Is there any other comaparator which does not use an open-collector at the output. Like LM397, or LM393 ?

Comment: @Delta_Shadow,  Comparators traditionally use open collector style outputs, if you want bipolar drive select a suitable OP-Amp instead.  Remember the commonmode input and output limits.

Answer (score 1):

LM339 has open collector outputs. The load must be against the + supply voltage. LM339 can't push out the +, it only sinks current. You're lucky, because the led needs a series resistor to keep the current safely low.

The following link has several circuits, also some with LM339.

http://www.bristolwatch.com/ele2/comparator.htm