# LM339N comparator won't work

Tags: comparator

I'm making a circuit which basically should turn on a led when it's dark and turn it off when there is more light. To test the light I've used a photoresistor, and to turn the led on/off a comparator (an LM339N). Here's my circuit:
[image]

My problem is that the led DOESN'T glow and there isn't any voltage/current on the comparator output. Why!? I checked it out, all the inputs works fine, their voltage is not 0.

Well, the generator is actually 10V, but it shouldn't matter I think (even with 5V it didn't work).

Comment: @Finbarr - I think you have a wrong link there. That Q is about op-amps.

Comment: You're right @PeterBennett - try [this one instead](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/283531/lm339-comparator-ic-is-not-responding-to-any-input)

Answer (score 7):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHvDmU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The above circuit should work(1)- the output as others have said is open collector so it can only sink current and not source it. You could also put the LED in series with R1 but it would be off (rather than on) when the output is high- so you could just swap the inputs.

(1) It is important that the common mode range of the LM339 inputs is respected. It is given in the datasheet as 0V to V+ - 2V so if the supply voltage is 10V, neither input should be above 8VDC or below ground. In fact with this particular comparator it **will** function provided at least one input is within the common mode range, so when the LDR is very dark it will function provided:

\$V_+\cdot \frac{R2}{R2+R4} >= 2.0\$

Answer (score 4):

Like most analog comparators, the LM339 has an open collector output.  That is, the output is an NPN transistor with emitter grounded and the collector connected only to the output pin, so the chip can only pull the output towards ground.  You need something outside the chip to pull the output High.

Connect your LED (Anode to the 339 output), in series with a ~510 Ohm resistor, to Vcc.  The LED will then light when the comparator output is Low.